# How to refresh UITableView with reloadData() on ViewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I would like to reload the data in my UITableView on ViewDidAppear and populate the table with the new data from a NSUserDefaults. I know everything works with the new information populating the table, because when I turn the emulator off and on again, the new data is there. But I want it to refresh with the new data everytime I display the view. It is a reminders app.

Here is my viewcontroller:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var reminderTableView: UITableView!

    var remindersArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("remindersArray")! as AnyObject as [String]

    let textCellIdentifier = "reminderText"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        reminderTableView.delegate = self
        reminderTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.reminderTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return remindersArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = remindersArray[row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

I have no idea why the function in viewWillAppear is not reloading the data in the table. Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried other solutions on stackoverflow, but none of those work for me unfortunately.

**EDIT**

Here is the second view controller which updates the remindersArray:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var reminderText: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addReminder(sender: AnyObject) {

        let newReminderText = reminderText.text

        var nsRemindersArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("remindersArray")! as NSArray

        var remindersArray = nsRemindersArray as AnyObject as [String]

        remindersArray.append(newReminderText)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(remindersArray, forKey: "remindersArray")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.reminderText.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }   

}
```

Comment: I noticed in one method you're using remberTableView and in the other, self.reminderTableView. Are you sure they're not nil?

Comment: What is happening in your app where you expect viewDidAppear to be called?

Comment: @LordZsolt I use self.reminderTableView in viewDidApper, because if I use it withou the self, I get an error, that suggests putting self. in front of it

Comment: Are you updating NSUserDefaults in a separate VC or another thread?  If so, you need to reload the remindersArray from NSUserDefaults before you run the table view reload.

Comment: @LouFranco nothing is happening actually, but I would like it to reload the data in the tableview

Comment: @pbasdf I am updating it in a different view, thanks for that, I will try to fix it using your remark

Comment: You should reload your remindersArray in ViewDidAppear. And AFTER that, reload your UITableView.

Comment: I think u forgot to call super.viewDidAppear(animated) at the top of viewDidAppear function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reloading the table, but you're not repopulating the `remindersArray`. Remember to re-retrieve the data from `NSUserDefaults` before calling `reloadData`.

Comment: do I still need to do that if I update the array from NSUserDefaults in another viewcontroller?

Comment: You haven't shown us the updating of this `remindersArray` property from the other view controller, but theoretically that could work. (I'd probably use a delegate-protocol pattern, if that were the case.) If you've tried that and it's not working, edit your question showing us that code, too.

Comment: I will edit the code and show you the second view controller where I update the array. Thank you for your time

Comment: That second view controller has its own rendition of `remindersArray`, only coincidentally having the same name, but you're not updating the array in the first view controller. The first view controller needs to either re-retrieve the contents of its own `remindersArray`, or you have to pass a pointer to the first to the second view controller so that the second view controller has some way of updating the first view controller's `remindersArray`.

Comment: yep, that was my problem, thank you very much for your solution!

Answer (score -4):

Just add a timer to have the 'update' code block repeat every .4 seconds...

```
Override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad

self.starttimer()

}



func starttimer(){
 var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update() {
    // update your data

self.tableview.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: That is stupid. So you reload your TableView every 0.4 seconds (also if nothing changes)